# onSelectionChange to display the value of the selected cell reference on another tab in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, selection, matching

This is a variation on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727937/onselectionchange-for-a-specific-google-sheets-tab/64728990#64728990) I posted about **onSelectionChange**.

Here is my [test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xqQe-zi6wAAki1apLNxy_3ZKjf0xRehHfJQO9_Skjdc) sheet.

**My goal**: if a cell in 'Sheet3'!A5:C9 is selected with the mouse/cursor, then 'Sheet3'!A1 = the corresponding cell in the sheet 'Reference'.

For example: if I click on A7, then A1 = 'Reference'!A7.

This was my first pass at a script, but it doesn't seem to  work:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if( as.getSheetID() == '2006534856' ) { return; }
  
  if (row>4 && row<10 && col<4)
       {as.getRange('A1').setValue(as.getSheetName('Reference').getRange(row,col).getValue());}
  
  else 
     {as.getRange('A1').setValue(" "); }

}
```

Comment: Explain  doesn't work by [edit]ing your question

Comment: I posted the solution. **But:** 1) As @TheMaster mentioned, when something does not work, you need to tell us if you see any error or unexpected behaviour.  2) When you decide to share a file with us, make it public so we can view it. 3) (Optional but recommended), if someone addresses your question and solves your issue, accept his answer so both that person and future readers can benefit from your question. I am not referring to my answer in this post, but to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727937/onselectionchange-for-a-specific-google-sheets-tab/64728990#64728990) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues / Explanation:

- Instead of `getSheetName('Reference')` you want to use `getSheetByName('Reference')`.
- `as` is the active sheet. Active sheet does not have a method `getSheetByName`. Instead, you want to get the spreadsheet. The way to do that using the event object is to use `e.source`. Therefore the final expression will be:

  `e.source.getSheetByName('Reference')`
- this `if( as.getSheetID() == '2006534856' ) { return; }` will terminate your function if the sheet ID is `2006534856`. Even if you did that on purpose, this is not a very good practice.
- instead, check if the name of the active sheet matches `Sheet3` and put also together the range conditions in the same `if` statement:

  `if( as.getName() == 'Sheet3' && row>4 && row<10 && col<4 )`

### Solution:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if( as.getName() == 'Sheet3' && row>4 && row<10 && col<4 ){
      as.getRange('A1').setValue(e.source.getSheetByName('Reference').getRange(row,col).getValue());
  }
  else{    
      as.getRange('A1').setValue('');
  }

}
```