# How can I limit the Range of onSelectionChange and set the values from selected row to other cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to limit the range when using onSelectionChange.
I have had some limited success with a few other onSelectionChange answers here but can't quite get it to do what I need..

Here is my [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbglIob51MGknoRWjQ9OeXdMcOeqpTb2gIWY_XRP1iw/edit?usp=sharing) outlining what I am trying to accomplish...

**GOAL:** I would like the **onSelectionChange(e)** to get the values in Col A:F in the selected row, IF the selected cell is in the named range of TESTsheet!A10:F (selecting any cell in rows 1-9 would not return any values)

The values from the selected row would be set in spisific cells.

**For example:**
If any cell in row 11 Col A-F was selected,
the values from A11, B11, C11, D11, E11, F11 would be set in B2, B4, B6, E2, E4, E6.

Here is an example.

**if row 11 is selected**
(the data in row 11 is copied to cells in rows 1,3,5):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Name | **Sean** |  | DEPT | **Physics** |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Last Name | **Smith** |  | STATE | **AK** |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | ID No. | **4685** |  | YEAR | **2006** |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | **1ST NAME** | **LAST NAME** | **ID No.** | **DEPT** | **STATE** | **YEAR** |
| 10 | Robert | Jones | 1587 | Art | MA | 1970 |
| **11** | **Sean** | **Smith** | **4685** | **Physics** | **AK** | **2006** |
| 12 | Karen | Davis | 6985 | English | NY | 1987 |
| 13 | Olivia | Carter | 7985 | Math | CA | 2019 |
| 14 | Ellen | James | 3587 | Music | NH | 1999 |

//

//

**if row 14 is selected**

(the data in row 14 is copied to cells in rows 1,3,5):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First Name | **Ellen** |  | DEPT | **Music** |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Last Name | **James** |  | STATE | **NH** |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | ID No. | **3587** |  | YEAR | **1999** |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | **1ST NAME** | **LAST NAME** | **ID No.** | **DEPT** | **STATE** | **YEAR** |
| 10 | Robert | Jones | 1587 | Art | MA | 1970 |
| 11 | Sean | Smith | 4685 | Physics | AK | 2006 |
| 12 | Karen | Davis | 6985 | English | NY | 1987 |
| 13 | Olivia | Carter | 7985 | Math | CA | 2019 |
| **14** | **Ellen** | **James** | **3587** | **Music** | **NH** | **1999** |

//

//

**I have gotten close with these answers:**

- [onSelectionChange to display the value of the selected cell reference on another tab in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930360/onselectionchange-to-display-the-value-of-the-selected-cell-reference-on-another)
- [onSelectionChange for a specific Google Sheets tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727937/onselectionchange-for-a-specific-google-sheets-tab/64728990#64728990)

Comment: This is the event object `{"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{},"user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":8,"rowStart":8}}
` so you do have access to the range which generated the trigger and you also potentially have some user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This limits the actions to columns A-F of your sheet name

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet2' && e.range.rowStart > 9 && e.range.rowStart < 100 && e.range.columnStart < 7) {
    //e.source.toast('flag');
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues().flat();
    ['B2','B4','B6','E2','E4','E6'].forEach((e,i) => sh.getRange(e).setValue(vs[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: this works but I also found another solution. See answer below.

Comment: This is working and seems to be a great solution. 
But it is working exactly backwards. It is writing the values in the specific cells [B2, B4, B6, E2, E4, E6]  to the selected row. 
I am unfamiliar with the .map in the vs const. Will see if I can figure out how to reverse it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you wanted.

Comment: sorry. the goal was the data from the selected row would be copied to the cells called out in const vs

Comment: Yeah I don't understand what you mean by that.  I probably need an example or two.  Also I will not follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: Added example table to question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want and your examples don't seem to match your explanation either where is the data coming from and going to.

Comment: So sorry. Thanks for the help. let me try again: The data is contained in A10:F100.  When any row 10 thru 100 is selected (row 11 in 1st example), the data from the selected row goes to cells  B2, B4, B6, E2, E4, E6.

Comment: oh it goes from the select row to B2,B4... Oh I had it the other way.  Sorry for the mixup

Comment: right! the top section of the sheet displays what is selected in the data below....

Comment: Okay try it now

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. I learned a lot on this one! This is part of a larger project and was completely stuck. Working now!!

Comment: Good.  Sorry it took so long to figure out what you required