# Run function when a google sheet is selected

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm looking for a method to run a function in google sheets when a sheet is selected.
Actually I found some standard trigger but I was not able to identify which could be ok to do this.
The function I want to activate is feeding a dropdown menu with file editors and I need to have it filled only when the sheet is selected.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `onSelectionChange()` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

See [onSelectionChange for a specific Google Sheets tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728160/13045193).