# Can You Prevent onSelectionChange() from Firing on Every Cell Clicked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am using `onSelectionChange` to navigate between a menu of Units and Tenants for a selected property. When you click on a given unit on the Unit Load Panel on the right, it loads the unit/tenant information into the form to the left of the panel.

[image: Unit Sheet with Units Load Panel on right hand side]

It works fine but from viewing the Executions log, I noticed that the onSelectionChange trigger is fired every time a cell is clicked anywhere, on any sheet in the entire spreadsheet. This makes sense because, as the code is written, it needs to check if the cells clicked are in the range specified in the if loop every time. However, this seems to be inefficient to me and unnecessary. Is there a way to restrict onSelectionChange to only fire if a cell is clicked in a specific range of cells?

Here is the code:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(); //Gets name of sheet where cell was clicked

  //row and column index of active (clicked) cell: 
  var range = e.range; //Activates range of clicked cell
  var row = range.getRow(); //Gets row # of clicked cell
  var col = range.getColumn(); // Gets col # of clicked cell
  
  // UNIT SHEET TRIGGERS:
  if(sheet == "Units"){
    var sheetUnits = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Units');
  
    //Variables for Units Load Panel (to switch between Units)
    var unitsRange = sheetUnits.getRange('L7:M41'); //highlights unit number list AND tenant name list on unit form tab
    var UnitID = sheetUnits.getRange('B10')// Sets Unit ID to be cell B10
    var UnitIDFirstCol = sheetUnits.getRange('N7').getColumn(); //Returns 14
    
    
        if( !sheetUnits.getRange(row,UnitIDFirstCol).isBlank() && col >= unitsRange.getColumn() && col <= unitsRange.getLastColumn() && row >= unitsRange.getRow() && row <= unitsRange.getLastRow()){

        UnitID.setValue(sheetUnits.getRange(row,UnitIDFirstCol).getValue()); //sets UnitID at top of unit form to be unit selected
        Unit_Load(); //Function that loads selected unit/tenant into form to the left
        }
      
  }
```

Comment: You answered your own question: they is no option in triggers to be fired only on specific ranges, you need to check it inside callback function

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're saying. Are you saying there's no way to prevent it from firing every time any cell on the spreadsheet is clicked?

Comment: `The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet.` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to limit how you respond to the trigger by using the event object show below:

```
{"authMode":"LIMITED","user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"source":{},"range": 
{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":6,"rowStart":6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to not log the `onSelectionChange` at all on the `Executions` section of the Apps Script editor, then this seems like it is not possible as also commented by **@Kos**.

### Suggestion

However, there's a workaround where you can add to your current `if` condition to only run your code when a specific range (rows & columns) is selected like:

> E.g. if you only want to run your code if cells within A5:A10 are selected

```
  if (sheet == 'Units' && row>4 && row<11 && col==1){ 
        //run code
  }else{
    return; //Automatically end your script
  }
```

This script was derived from this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728160).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I'm already doing except with two sets of if loops - the first checks if the user is selecting a cell on the Units tab and the second checks if the user has clicked a particular cell. I need to keep it as two different loops since different cells aka "buttons" do different things. Yes, I was asking about it not firing every time a random cell is clicked. Sounds like that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to "Prevent onSelectionChange() from Firing on Every Cell Clicked?" but you could use a *JavaScript control statement* to limit when certain parts of your code are executed.

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  if(e.range.rowStart === 1 && e.range.columnStart === 1){
    // This part will be executed when A1 is selected
  } else {
    // This part will be executed when any cell but not A1 is selected
  }
}
```

Please note that the if statement is the first statement in the `onSelectionChange` code and that it doesn't need any time execution "expensive" methods.

All the `SpreasheetApp` methods are relatively expensive compared to a JavaScript comparison. Considering Google Apps Script has time executions quotas for triggers this might be relevant, specially if Google Sheets users will be using free Google accounts to work on spreadsheets with time execution intensive triggers.

From Exception messages in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas:

> - `Service using too much computer time for one day`. This indicates that the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.

Related

- [How do I add an Apps Script function to a Google Sheets cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/159611/88163)

Comment: I believe my code is already doing this but thank you

Comment: Have you read the text above the code? --- > "It's not possible..." and yes, the code in the question has if statements but it  has "expensive" redundant statements like getRow, get Column before them.